# Columns in section tag stack on top of each other instead of next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have three columns inside a section tag in HTML but they sit on top of each other instead of standing next to eachother.

```
<section class="sec-top">
    <div style="background-color:#f4f5f9">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 style="padding-left: 100px; padding-top:40px; color:#3d7cc9;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
            <p style="padding-left:100px;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac pharetra turpis. Sed vitae orci.
            </p>
            <ul class="checkmark">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Duis eu lorem ut risus sollicitudin bibendum.</li>
                <li>uspendisse malesuada augue sit amet ipsum laoreet, eget consequat purus consequat.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <img class="gify" src="../../assets/apps.gif" />
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="backgroundBlue">
                <h2 class="ptop">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.s</h3>
                <iframe width="90%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or why this is happening. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the css for `column`?

Comment: .column {
    width:33%;
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `div` is a block-level element. That means that even if you reduce it's `width` it will still cause a new line to be created:

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it
>   can). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow

You need to either change the `display` value of `.column` (or its parent) or remove it from the normal flow with a `float`.

See examples below.

In the first example, I added `float:left` to the `column` class. This removes each column from the normal flow and they are stacked to the left of the screen.

In the second example, I changed the container `div` to the flexbox model and added `flex: 1 1 33%` to each `column`. This will cause each column to always take up 33% of the width of the parent. Here is a great resource on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.column {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.gify {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.flex-parent>.column {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec-top">
    <strong>Using Float</strong>
    <div style="background-color:#f4f5f9;" class="clearfix">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 style="padding-left: 100px; padding-top:40px; color:#3d7cc9;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
            <p style="padding-left:100px;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac pharetra turpis. Sed vitae orci.
            </p>
            <ul class="checkmark">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Duis eu lorem ut risus sollicitudin bibendum.</li>
                <li>uspendisse malesuada augue sit amet ipsum laoreet, eget consequat purus consequat.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <img class="gify" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" />
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="backgroundBlue">
                <h2 class="ptop">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.s</h3>
                <iframe width="90%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="sec-top" style="margin-top:30px">
    <strong>Using FlexBox</strong>
    <div style="background-color:#f4f5f9;" class="flex-parent">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 style="padding-left: 100px; padding-top:40px; color:#3d7cc9;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
            <p style="padding-left:100px;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac pharetra turpis. Sed vitae orci.
            </p>
            <ul class="checkmark">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Duis eu lorem ut risus sollicitudin bibendum.</li>
                <li>uspendisse malesuada augue sit amet ipsum laoreet, eget consequat purus consequat.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <img class="gify" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" />
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="backgroundBlue">
                <h2 class="ptop">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.s</h3>
                <iframe width="90%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what if i want to put another section below this one? @wlh

Comment: I gave you an example with two sections above. You will have to extrapolate from there.